# How to extract letter from an image using pytesseract

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, python-tesseract

my problem is that I have an image that is this [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53wU6.jpg) and I would like to know how to extract all the letters that can be seen in it. I have already tried with pytesseract but it returns me HANUTG and it therefore forgets the I. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

im = cv2.imread("crop1.jpg")

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe' 
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config='--psm 13 --oem 1 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'))
```

It is not very long but sufficient to extract the letters except apparently the I, I tested with other letters and there are some others who are not recognized too, how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the image before feeding it to the tesseract as input when you couldn't get the desired output.

For example:

You could apply some [adaptive-thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) and add some [white-borders](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/dc/da3/tutorial_copyMakeBorder.html) to the current image. Results:

| Adaptive-thresh result | White-border |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

now when you feed it to the tesseract:

```
H | AN U T G
```

Code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

bgr_img = cv2.imread("53wU6.jpg")  # Load the image
gry_img = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry_img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 21)
border_img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(gry_img, 50, 50, 50, 50, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=255)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(border_img, config='--psm 6')
print(txt)
```

Suggested reading: [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)